# Merging multiple errors on laravel validator

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel validator. Here is my rules and error messages;

```
   $rules = array(
        'a' => 'required',
        'b' => 'required',
    );
    $messages = array(
        'required' => 'Missing parameter(s).',
   );

   $validator = Validator::make($postData, $rules, $messages);

   if ($validator->fails()) {
        $json['missing'] = array_keys($validator->failed());

   $messages = $validator->messages();

   foreach ($messages->all() as $message){
        $return['error'][] = $message."<br>";
   }
   }
```

When both inputs are empty it returns error message for multiple times.

```
Missing parameter(s).
Missing parameter(s).
```

I want to get only one error message for per rule. How can i do that simply?

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
foreach ($messages->all() as $message)
{
    $return['error'][$message] = $message."<br>";
}
```

They should merge.